# Calculate a base64 encoded MD5 hash for Amazon MWS in Delphi Indy10

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services, delphi-xe2, indy10

I am trying to submit a feed to Amazon MWS. The problem is that Amazon says that the Md5 hash I submitted does not match their calculations, so my request was rejected.

This is the code i use to calculate the hash:

```
    var
        StringStream: TStringStream;
        MessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
        XMLString: string;
    begin
        MessageDigest := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
        StringStream := TStringStream.Create;
        try
            StringStream.WriteString(XMLString);
            HashString := MessageDigest.HashStream(StringStream);

        finally
            StringStream.Free;
            MessageDigest.Free;
        end;
    end;
```

And this is the response from Amazon:

```
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
        <Error>
            <Type>Sender</Type>
            <Code>ContentMD5DoesNotMatch</Code>
            <Message>the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed (H3GnH3X3H3auHZ0mGZ8mD4KvE30mEJauHKD6E3GoDqK) did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed (fSEMn6SCuSia5YVdz/1NqQ==)</Message>
            <Detail />
        </Error>
        <RequestID>9c3e0b2a-c418-41dc-b733-e55ac01343b1</RequestID>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

What is the proper way to calculate a base64 encoded MD5 hash? Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance, and regards.

P.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
StringStream := TStringStream.Create;
try
  StringStream.WriteString(XMLString);
```

To this:

```
StringStream := TStringStream.Create(XMLString);
```

Or this:

```
StringStream := TStringStream.Create;
try
  StringStream.WriteString(XMLString);
  StringStream.Position := 0;
```

Either way, also keep in mind that in XE2, `String` is unicode and `TStringStream` is `TEncoding`-aware, so make sure you are encoding the string to the correct charset before it is hashed, eg:

```
StringStream := TStringStream.Create(XMLString, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Lastly, `TIdHash` has a `HashString()` (and `HashStringAsHex()`) method so you don't need to handle `TStream` manually:

```
HashString := MessageDigest.HashString(XMLString, IndyUTF8Encoding);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. HashString returns a TArray<System.Byte> and I am not sure if my conversion is correct. Furthermore, the result string is supposed to be base64 encoded. Here is the snippet:  
`HashArray := MessageDigest.HashString(XMLText, IndyUTF8Encoding);  
SetString(HashString, PAnsiChar(@HashArray[0]), Length(HashArray));  
TextEdit.Text := EncodeBase64(HashString);  `
  
Am doing this correctly?

Comment: I apologize for the numerous edits, I am not familiar with formatting the comments.

Comment: I can't answer whether the conversion is correct because you don't show what `EncodeBase64()` expects as input and such. However, Indy has its own base64 encoder via the `TIdEncoderMIME` class, which can encode a byte array directly without needing it copied to a string first.